# Cordova social sharing plugin didnt work in android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have installed  [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)  Cordova social sharing plugin via command line tool.
Everything is added correctly to my current project foleder,but the share option is didn't work
Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and link', null, null, 'http://www.x-services.nl');
       }
```

I will get this error in my console

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'share' of undefined

My Cordova version is 5.1.1

**EDIT**

I've crated a blank Cordova project and added the plugin its works fine for me
there is no need of manual configuration.
But my project developed using Angularjs and Onsenui,may this was the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include socialsharing.js in your project and load it like this?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/socialsharing.js"></script>`

Make sure the S are not upper case in the file name too...

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error in console in google chrome console ?? in any browser not supported cordova plugin so you have to test in device and you have to also include file in hader

```
 <script charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js">
    </script>


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only')"
   }
```

and if you have any further confusion then message me